# Prove that if f meromorphic in U and $(z_{n})_{n\geq 1} \to z^{*}$ in U and f has a pole $\forall n \in z_{n}$. Then $z^{*}$ is a pole of f.

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

U $\subset \mathbb{C} $ is an open set and f is a meromorphic function in U. Prove that if $(z_{n})_{n\geq 1} $ is a sequence in U that converges to a certain $z^{*} \in U$ and the function f has a pole in $z_{n}$ for every n, then f has a pole in $z^{*}$.

I have been trying to prove this, knowing that this is impossible.I am trying to show the contradiction.

### Here is the definition of a pole:

A function f of a complex variable z is meromorphic in the neighbourhood of a point ${\displaystyle z_{0},}$  if either f or its reciprocal function 1/f is holomorphic in some neighbourhood of ${\displaystyle z_{0}} $ (that is, if f or 1/f is differentiable in a neighbourhood of ${\displaystyle z_{0}})$ ''neighbourhood  means a disc centered at $z_{0}$ of radius $\varepsilon$;   $D(z_{0},\varepsilon)$ ''. If ${\displaystyle z_{0}} $ is a singularity of 1/f , then it is a pole of f.

### My solution:

My argument is basically since the sequence $z_{n}$ is convergent then

$lim_{n \to \infty } |z_{n+1}-z_{n}|=0$

then if $z^{*}$ is a pole of f, then f has to be holomorphic on $D(z^{*},\varepsilon)$. But this is then impossible because no matter how small we choose $\varepsilon$ there will be always a pole in the radius we choose  because of this condition $lim_{n \to \infty } |z_{n+1}-z_{n}|=0$.

So basically this is the way i was trying to prove it but i find it not rigorous enough or incomplete. I am trying to prove it in a rigorous mathematical way.

Comment: “If $f$ is holomorphic in $U$” and “$f$ has a pole in $z_n \in U$” are contradictory statements.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, i made the mistake of writing holomophic instead of meromorphic.

Comment: What is your definition of a pole? Isn't it by definition an isolated singularity? (In which case it cannot be the limit of a sequence of poles unless that sequence is eventually constant)

Comment: $z^*$ is definitely NOT an isolated singularity!

Comment: Your assumption $z^{*} \in U$ already implies that $f$ is either holomorphic in a neighbourhood of $z^{*} $ or has a pole at $z^{*} $. In either case, $z^{*} $ cannot be the limit of poles of $f$. – Are you sure that you stated the problem correctly? In its present form it does not make much sense.

Comment: unfortunately it is the right statement, in this case f must be holomorphic in a disc of D(z∗,ε). I have to show a contradiction with the statement.

Comment: Under the assumptions, as pointed by other comments, the only possible behavior of $(z_n)$ is that in fact $z_n = z^*$ for all sufficiently large $n$. Then the conclusion becomes quite trivial...